# Google play service can't load leaderboard users images

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm trying to save a list of `Texture2D`s from the leaderboard but it always ends up to be empty (even if I keep it loading for a while).

```
public void LoadUsernames()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < usersData.Count; i++)
    {
        usersIds.Add(usersData[i].userID); //Get all the usersId inside usersData
    }

    Social.LoadUsers(usersIds.ToArray(), (users) =>
    {
        foreach (IScore score in usersData)
        {
            IUserProfile user = FindUser(users, score.userID);
            if (user != null)
            {
                usersName.Add(user.userName);
                usersTexture.Add(user.image);
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine(LoadingUsersName());
    });
}
```

Once the Textures are stored inside `usersTexture` I've got a raw image and I simply adding every single texture to the raw images, but `usersTextures` always ends up empty. I've tried to in the same way `Social.localUser.image` to the raw image and it works.

Comment: I can't tell if the code you posted is the code that doesn't work, or the code that does work (the `Social.localUser.image` way mentioned). In addition, the `LoadingUsersName` method is referenced here, but it is not clear if this is important to the question.

Comment: @Draco18s sorry you're right. LoadingUsers isn't important it just wait for the usersName to become avabile (it's a while(usersName.Contains(null)). 

The code works, but usersTexture always contains nothing, the count is always 0 even if i take the users reference and let it load. 

Social.localUser.Image works but i don't need that image, i just mentioned it to let you know that other images are loaded inside my raw images.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I haven't messed with Google Play services, but I thought that info might help out someone else who has.

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for your time. I hope someone can help me to figure this out. I'm asking everywhere but none is answering